# Problema no loop com switch case

Tags: c, menu

Eu refiz o codigo seguindo as orientações passadas aqui. Porem, voltou a ter o problema inicial... eu escolho a opção desejada, ele executa a ação desejada mas logo depois vai pro default do switch case e imprime "informação invalida"

Meu código está assim:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define TAM 20
#include <ctype.h>

int menu(){
    char opc;

    printf("| A | Ler string\n");
    printf("| B | Tamanho da string1\n");
    printf("| C | Comparar strings\n");
    printf("| D | Concatenar strings\n");
    printf("| E | Imprimir string1 invertida\n");
    printf("| F | Quantidade de ocorrencias de um caractere na string1\n");
    printf("| G | Subsituir o primeiro caractere1 pelo caractere2\n");
    printf("| H | Retornar substring da string1\n");
    printf("| I | Sair\n");
    scanf("%c", &opc);

    return tolower(opc);
}


void pedirstr1(char *str1){

        printf("Entre com a string1: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        fgets(str1, TAM, stdin);
        str1[strlen(str1)-1] = '\0';
}

void pedirstr2(char *str2){

        printf("Entre com a string1: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        fgets(str2, TAM, stdin);
        str2[strlen(str2)-1] = '\0';
}


int main(){
    char str1[TAM] = " NULL ", str2[TAM] = " NULL ", char1, char2, c, opc = 'f', sair=0, c2, junto[TAM];
    int inicio, fim, contchar = 0;


    do {
        opc = menu();
        printf("\n\n");

        switch(opc){

        case 'a':
                //system("CLS");

                pedirstr1(str1);

                break;

        case 'b':
                //system("CLS");

                if (strcmp(str1, " NULL ") == 0){
                    printf("Nao existe nenhum valor na string1.\n");
                    printf("\n\n");
                } else {
                    printf("O tamanho da string1 e: %d\n", strlen(str1));
                    printf("\n\n");
                }

                break;

        case 'c':
                //system("CLS");

                pedirstr1(str1);
                pedirstr2(str2);

                if (strcmpi(str1, str2) == 0){
                    printf("As strings 1 e 2 sao iguais.\n");
                    printf("\n\n");
                } else {
                    printf("As strings 1 e 2 sao diferentes. \n");
                    printf("\n\n");
                }

                break;

        case 'd':
                //system("CLS");

                pedirstr1(str1);

                pedirstr2(str2);

                printf("string1 + string2 = %s%s\n", str1, str2); //posso usar strcat mas da ruim pq fica armazenado na variavel
                printf("\n\n");

                break;

        case 'e':
                //system("CLS");

                pedirstr1(str1);

                printf("String1 invertida: ");
                for (c=strlen(str1); c>=0; c--){
                    printf("%c", str1[c]);
                }

                printf("\n\n");

                break;

        case 'f':
                //system("CLS");

                pedirstr1(str1);

                printf("Letra que deseja contar: ");
                scanf("%c", &char1);

                for (c=0; c<strlen(str1); c++){
                    if (str1[c] == char1){
                        contchar ++;
                    }
                }

                printf("A letra %c aparece %d vezes na string1.\n", char1, contchar);
                printf("\n\n");

                break;

        case 'g':
                //system("CLS");

                pedirstr1(str1);

                printf("Entre com o caractere que deseja substituir: [diferencie maiusculas de minusculas]");
                scanf("%c", &char1);

                printf("Qual caractere deseja colocar no lugar? ");
                scanf("%c", &char2);

                for (c=0; c<strlen(str1); c++){
                    if (str1[c] == char1){
                        str1[c] = char2;
                    }
                }

                printf("Nova string: %s", str1);
                printf("\n\n");

                break;

        case 'h':
                //system("CLS");

                pedirstr1(str1);

                printf("A partir de qual posicao? ");
                scanf("%d", &inicio);

                printf("Até onde? ");
                scanf("%d", &fim);

                while (inicio > fim){
                    printf("A posicao de inicio deve ser menor do que a do fim. \n");

                    printf("A partir de qual posicao? ");
                    scanf("%d", &inicio);

                    printf("Ate onde? ");
                    scanf("%d", &fim);
                }

                printf("Substring: ");
                for (c=inicio; c<fim; c++){
                    printf("%c", str1[c]);
                }

                printf("\n\n");

                break;
        case 'i':
                sair = 1;

                break;

        default:
                //system("CLS");

                printf("Informacao invalida, tente novamente. \n");
                printf("\n\n");

                break;
        }
    } while (!sair);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Se você colocar um `fflush(stdin);` após o `scanf` da função `menu`, o que acontece? E se você colocar antes?

Comment: AAAAA FUNCIONOU

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tens o `opc = menu();` fora do teu `do while`. Ou seja a tua variável `opc` não actualiza após cada ciclo fica sempre a mesma e mantém o 1º valor introduzido.

Exprimenta:

```
do {
    opc = menu();
    switch(opc){

    //resto do codigo

    }
} while (!sair);
```

Comment: Tu estás a usar `"NULL"`  ou seja a string null e não o valor `NULL` e como estás a fazer o `strcmp()` e tens diferente nº de espaços na tua string `"NULL"` vai dar errado exemplo: `"NULL    "` !=  `"     NULL"`.
Usa o valor NULL e não uma string com uma palavra, `str1[TAM] = NULL`.

Comment: Eu tentei colocar str1[TAM] = NULL, porem deu o erro "invalid initializer".Então resolvi tirar o teste pra ver se ja tinha algo na string, deixei ele apenas pedindo. porem continua com o mesmo problema citado acima. entao, eu testei ja colocando um valor na opc. por ex opc = 'f'. Dessa maneira, ele funcionou! pq quando eu peço pro usuario entrar com a opc ele não funciona corretamente?

Comment: `char str1[TAM]  str2[TAM],` e assim? Supostamente devem ser iniciadas por default a `NULL`

Comment: Mas em que case é que não funciona especificamente?

Comment: Eu editei a pergunta, pois fica mais facil de explicar por la

Comment: `scanf("%c", &opc);` porque é que tens `&opc` e não só `opc`?

Comment: mas se não colocar o & ele não guarda na memoria

Comment: Eu estive a ver e não encontro mais erro nenhum, espera que outra pessoa venha dar uma vista de olhos, desculpa eu não poder ajudar mais :(

Comment: tudo bem, sem problema. de qualquer forma, muito obrigada

Comment: Experimenta dar um print a `opc, str1, str2` antes do case para ver o que é que eles tem como valores guardados isso talvez ajude a fazer debug mais facilmente.

Comment: E já agora pergunta estúpida deste compile depois de teres feito as alterações, não estás só a correr o exec?

Comment: kkkk queria que o problema fosse esse. ate conferi aqui pra ter 100% de certeza... não e isso ;-;

Comment: Nunca se sabe, não seria a 1ª vez xD, mas faz um print do opc depois de seleccionares o opc.

Answer (score 2):

Adicione

```
getchar();
```

Depois de

```
scanf("%c", &opc);
```

Quando você escolhe uma opção que não é de leitura e tecla `ENTER`. Ele realizar a operação que você escolheu e entende o `ENTER` que você deu como uma opção que você digitou também, com isso ele entra no default.